# mysql 5.7 appending key/value to nested json object

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-5.7

I'm trying the new API for mysql 5.7 which deals with JSON columns.  My `test` column looks like this:

```
{"foo":{"efg":1}, "bar":{"abc":0}}
```

What I would like to do is append to one of the keys, for example `foo` so it will result in `"foo":{"efg":1, "klm":2}`.  What I've tried so far following [their documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html):

```
mysql> select json_insert(test, '$.foo', 10, '$.foo.klm', 2) from table1
       where name='Joe';
```

What that does is replace `"efg":1` and the result is `"foo":{"klm":2}`.

```
mysql> select json_array_append(test, '$.foo', '{"klm":2}') from table1 where
       name="Joe';
```

The above line obviously converts `foo` into an array `"foo":[{"efg":1}, {"klm":2}]`, which is not what I want.

I've tried combining queries together:

```
mysql> select json_insert(test, '$.foo', 10, '$.foo', 
       select json_merge(select json_extract(test, '$.foo') from table1 
       where name="Joe"), '{"klm":2}') from table1 where name="Joe";
```

That just gives me a syntax error `near select json_extract(test, '$.foo')`.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson the desired result should be `{"foo":{"efg":1, "klm":2}, "bar":{"abc":0}}`.  Their documentation mostly works with modifying arrays but I would like to keep everything as an Object.

Comment: I get that exact result using your `json_insert`, (or just `select json_insert(test, '$.foo.klm', 2) from table1 where name='Joe';` `"efg":1` does not disappear for me.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I'm not sure where the problem is then.  I emitted some parameters, like in your comment, and it still replaces everything for the `"foo"` Object.

Comment: How about `select json_merge(test, '{"foo":{"klm":2}}') FROM table1;`? Still dropping `efg`?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson still dropping.  The only way to keep it is explicitly adding all the values, as in `select json_insert(test, '$.foo.efg', 1, '$.foo.klm', 2) from...`

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson is there a way to combine the queries, like I tried doing in my last example in the original question?

Comment: What is your exact MySQL version? I can't seem to find a way to repeat on 5.7.11.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Server version: 5.7.11 MySQL Community Server (GPL), downloaded last night.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem.

Test:

```sql
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.11    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @`test` := '{"foo": {"efg":1}, "bar": {"abc":0}}';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT JSON_INSERT(@`test`,/*'$.foo', 10,*/ '$.foo.klm', 2);
+--------------------------------------------------+
| JSON_INSERT(@`test`, '$.foo.klm', 2)             |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| {"bar": {"abc": 0}, "foo": {"efg": 1, "klm": 2}} |
+--------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**UPDATE**

```sql
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table1`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1` (
    -> `id` INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    -> `test` JSON
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `table1`
    ->     (`test`)
    -> VALUES
    ->     ('{"foo": {"efg":1}, "bar": {"abc":0}}');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT `id`, `test` FROM `table1`;
+----+----------------------------------------+
| id | test                                   |
+----+----------------------------------------+
|  1 | {"bar": {"abc": 0}, "foo": {"efg": 1}} |
+----+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT JSON_INSERT(@`test`, '$.foo.klm', 2)
    -> FROM `table1`
    -> WHERE `id` = 1;
+--------------------------------------------------+
| JSON_INSERT(@`test`, '$.foo.klm', 2)             |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| {"bar": {"abc": 0}, "foo": {"efg": 1, "klm": 2}} |
+--------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> UPDATE `table1`
    -> SET `test` = JSON_INSERT(@`test`, '$.foo.klm', 2)
    -> WHERE `id` = 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT `id`, `test` FROM `table1`;
+----+--------------------------------------------------+
| id | test                                             |
+----+--------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | {"bar": {"abc": 0}, "foo": {"efg": 1, "klm": 2}} |
+----+--------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: When I executed word for word from your example, it worked correctly.  So maybe initially added the Object incorrectly into the row?  I added it directly inside `insert into table1 (test) values ('{"foo":{"efg":1}, "bar":{"abc":0}}');`.  Is that the problem?

Comment: @denikov: Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'll try it in a couple hours and hopefully figure it out. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Still have no idea what wrong, only the update statement does what it's supposed to.